# Centering a description list so the description term and descriptions are all aligned vertically

Tags: html, css

I'm trying center all the content in the description list so they all start at the same margin for each line. The  have move words so they are not aligned with the .

```css
list {
  font-weight: 360;
  margin-right: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: inside;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="list">
  <dl>
    <dt>Phone:</dt>
    <dd>412-719-1936</dd><br>
    <dt>Email:</dt>
    <dd>rickwilson88@gmail.com</dd><br>
    <dt>Address:</dt>
    <dd>2475 Leis Lane</dd>
    <dd>Bethel Park, PA 15102</dd>
  </dl>
```

Comment: Can you show an image of the current and the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add (#) to css selector of your id="list":

```
   #list {
        font-weight:400; // note: font weight takes values: 100,200,..etc
        margin-right:100px;
        text-align:center;
        list-style: inside;
        display: inline-block; 
   }
```